# Filter Typescript Type based on substring key

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have typescript Type

```
type AllTypes = "hello.world"|"love.typescript"|"learn.typescript"|"love.stackoverflow"
```

How can I pick types from AllTypes based on substring "typescript"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to extract just those members of the `AllTypes` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) which are assignable to an appropriate *pattern* [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) (containing `` `${string}` ``, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)):

```
type AllTypes = "hello.world" | "love.typescript" | 
  "learn.typescript" | "love.stackoverflow";

type X = Extract<AllTypes, `${string}typescript${string}`>;
// type X = "love.typescript" | "learn.typescript"
```

The type `` `${string}typescript${string}` `` corresponds to all strings containing the substring `"typescript"`, as `` `${string}` `` corresponds to any string, including the empty string.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.8.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAKuCBnKBeKAiAFhBAewDoB3QgJzgBNsoAfHOQgNwmNElQGMKBLMMDqNscCAEMKAOw4oe-QcKat2qYOO4BrFRQBmzUtgCwAKFOdoADUxQAogA9gFDcAA88JHIA0UAAYASAG81fikAcwBfC3kBYCCQvnCI3wA+AG5TAHpMqAsoayxRFVkuXlilUQlpErQyxSA)